# wxWidgets program increase CPU usage

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm working on a wxWidgets program which is very similar to the wxWiki "Making a render loop" example using idle event. I modified the display panel to show a background image, a blinking text and an animation.

```
void MyApp::onIdle(wxIdleEvent& evt)
{
    if(render_loop_on)
    {
        drawPane->paintNow();

        while(Pending())
            Dispatch();
        evt.RequestMore();
    }
}

BasicDrawPane::BasicDrawPane(wxFrame* parent) :
wxPanel(parent)
{
    wxBitmap background;
    background.LoadFile("background.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
    m_pBackground = new wxStaticBitmap(this, -1, background);
    m_pBackground->Show();

    m_pText = new wxStaticText(this, -1, wxT("blinking"), wxPoint(400, 10));
    m_pText->Show();
    m_bShow = false;

    wxAnimation iconAni;
    iconAni.LoadFile("animation.gif");
    m_wxIconAnimationCtrl = new wxAnimationCtrl(this, -1, iconAni);
    m_wxIconAnimationCtrl->Play();
}

void BasicDrawPane::paintNow()
{
    m_bShow = !m_bShow;
    m_pText->Show(m_bShow);
}
```

I added the **Dispatch** function because without it the memory and CPU usage will increase linearly after program starts, but even with the **Dispatch** function the CPU usage will climb gradually after running for a few hours. CPU usage will be stable only when I display the background alone.

I did the test with wxWidgets 2.8.11 on puppy linux, can anyone advise it?

Comment: it seems like the animation will generate more wxIdleEvent outside the MyApp::onIdle handle so that more and more idle events will be pushed into the queue, but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is totally normal, that for this program the cpu usage increases. Look at the documentation of "[RequestMore](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxidleevent.html#wxidleeventrequestmore)". This basically loops the idle-function so it is called repeatedly.

Solution:

Use a wxTimer for blinking the Text and remove the idle function.

edit:

Tipp of the Day (:D): Use wxWidgets 2.9.x, it contains a lot of bugfixes and improvements :).

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, in my project I need to use idle event loop to process some real time tasks. If use wxTimer method, I have to set the interval to a very short time and that may the UI very lagging.

Comment: Well, you still can use the idlefunc for other stuff, but you could remove the blinking from it. At least it would take off *some* load from the cpu. And you could also time your blink better or does it have to blink as fast as it can?

Comment: I removed the blinking text and found the problem was mainly caused by the animation itself. And I tried to distinguish the idle event from the animation and from the onIdle function. But evt.GetId(), evt.GetTimestamp() always return 0 and there is no way to filter out unwanted idle events

Comment: You could try to use 2.9.2 or 2.9.3 and see if it resolves the issue. It is labeled "unstable", but is really usuable. The 2.9.x Code contains so many fixes and improvements.. but then it is just a workaround. Also, did you try to use GetEventType() instead?

Comment: update to version 2.9.2 does not help, maybe it is not consider as bug to wxWidgets development group. GetEventType() always return same value since they are all idle events. I also tried to stop the idle event which generated by the animation from propagating from BasicDrawPane to MyApp, however, it filter out all other idle events as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
evt.RequestMore();
```

with

```
if( ! evt.MoreRequested() )
   evt.RequestMore();
```

Comment: that's not work, MoreRequested() already return false no matter where the idle event come from